# CodeIgniter showing query string instead of URI segments

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, get

I have this form:

```
<form name = "search" action="" method="GET">
    <input name="first" type="text" value="First"/>
    <input name="second" type="text" value="Second"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and following config file:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']= 'd'; // experimental not currently in use
```

But when I click submit, it is passing values as query string and not as URI segments. I need to have the URI segments enabled. How can I do this?

Comment: What I need is, when I click on Submit button, the URL should be changed to URI segments with submitted data instead of query string

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass all parameters as URI segments, then you just submit your form from controller. it will automatically convert your parameters into URI segments.

otherwise from View it is not possible to make as URI segments.

have a look at :http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

Comment: Thanks. But how can I prevent from passing the empty values in query string ? The GET method is needed as this will share the URL with people and they will get the same data

Comment: Ohk.  Then try using jQuery function call on submit of form.
on submitting FORM the jQuery function will serialize all data of your FORM. and manually made URI segments. then return to your window.location......